# Retrieve comments on runtime?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to call **Ajax** which **fetches** all the comments from database.

Now how to put a check on that **Ajax Script** to Run, when only someone comments.

Same as the **stackoverflow notifications**. When we comment on question, The Notification appears without reloading page (i.e On Runtime ).

Right now I am Running the same Ajax Script after each 10 seconds again and again, when I think is a bad way .So Here is my working Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_files/reload_notifications.php"
        }).done(function(result) {
            var $notifications = $('#notification_area');
            if ($notifications.length > 0) {

                $notifications.html(result);

            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Use HTML5 Server Sent Events, its better

Comment: @JasonOOO can you please give me some example? Or help using it with my code . I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Use _.append()_ instaed of _.html()_.

Comment: just try with Google [server sent events example php](https://www.google.iq/?gws_rd=cr&ei=mXZEUpCbOvT04QTD3IDIDA#q=server+sent+events+example+php)

Comment: @GurminderSingh No dear thats not the problem here. I want to find out when the comment hits on Database, So at the same time only my Script should run

Answer (score 1):

When a comment is entered, do a similar AJAX request that will save the comment and on it's *success callback*, call another function which will also hit another AJAX request which fetches the comments. For e.g.

```
 function insertComment() {
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax_files/insert_comment.php"
      }).done(function(result) {
          fetchComments();
        }
   });
 }

 function fetchComments() {
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax_files/reload_notifications.php"
     }).done(function(result) {
        var $notifications = $('#notification_area');
        if ($notifications.length > 0) {

            $notifications.html(result);

        }
   });
 }
```

Hope this helps!